# Saving a bitmap image on an Access form as a .bmp file using vba

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, bitmapimage

My end goal is to insert an image into a bookmark on word as part of a larger report. Using information on an access database submitted via a form.

I can insert an image into a word bookmark using vba if the image is saved to a file on my computer.

However i can't work out how to save a bitmap image in my access form to a file on my computer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've been trying to do it using SaveToFile but not having any success.

Using the code below i keep getting the error 'Object Required'.

```
Private Sub SaveImages_Click()

'Attempting to save bitmap image from database to file, then delete the 
image from the database.
Dim data As DAO.Recordset
Set data = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Tbl1")
vID = Me.Visit_ID
 While data.EOF = False
            'Check for match
            If data.Fields.Item(25).Value = vID Then
            'Get Value
            data.Fields(48).Value.SaveToFile ("C:temp")
            'Exit Loop
            data.MoveLast
            End If
            data.MoveNext
        Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: `data.Fields(48)`is an ole field with the bitmap? `.SaveToFile`is for attachments only

Comment: Yes data.Fields(48) is an OLE field containing bitmap. Is there another way i could try?

Comment: On x86 Office, you can try [Lebans OleToDisk](http://www.lebans.com/oletodisk.htm).

Comment: I've seen this but i would like to be able to integrate it within my own form, as currently i add a screenshot to the OLE object, then edit it in paint before trying to save it and export to a word document.

Comment: You can use it on your own form too, but you shouldn't store images as ole, save them in filesystem and store parh in db!

Comment: Would i still be able to edit the pictures in the form by doing that method? Would you be able to show me some example code, thanks for the advice btw.

Comment: How do you edit the images in the form? Context menu -> Bitmap Image Object -> Edit? That can be emulated simply by opening the stored file. Extract all oles with OleToDisk, save the path to the files in a new text-field in the table and use the iinks with an image object.

Comment: So step one  would be to save image from clipboard to file directly. Then add image to form using storepath. Then edit the image. Then re-save to file using OLEToDisk? Thanks for the advice.

Comment: OleToDisk is just used for export of the actual saved oles. Later you want to avoid bound oles . You edit images by opening from file with app (e.g. Paint), then edit and save. You should explain your current workflow. You add images from clipboard? What else?